# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

Not really sure where to go from here.  Trying to install Sitecore 9 and have gotten to this point and can't seem to get beyond it.  It tells me that the property value cannot be found, but I have no idea what property value or how to even turn more debug information on - note I change the name to something.xconnect - it was using the correct prefix because it did set up the website in IIS and created the folder under the webroot(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\something.xconnect) as I would have expected.   Any pointers to help get me on track would be greatly appreciated since this is my first install and it is turning out to be painful.  I know that there was anothing post similar related to value and I checked those things and it didn't seem like it was any of those things, but went through and did check that before posting this.

[------------------------------------------- CreateWebsite : Website -------------------------------------------------]
[CreateWebsite]:[Exists] something.xconnect
[CreateWebsite]:[Setting] applicationPool => something.xconnect
[CreateWebsite]:[Setting] physicalPath => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\something.xconnect
[--------------------------------------------- StopWebsite : ManageWebsite -------------------------------------------]
[StopWebsite]:[Stop] something.xconnect

---

Command start time: 20181002193908

---

PS>TerminatingError(CheckWebsiteState): "The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists."

> > TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists."
> >     TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists."
> >     Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> >     At C:\deploy\Sitecore-Commerce-Install-Scripts\sc-install\scripts\Install-Sitecore-XP.ps1:44 char:1
> >     + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
> >     Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
> >     At C:\deploy\Sitecore-Commerce-Install-Scripts\sc-install\scripts\Install-Sitecore-XP.ps1:44 char:1
> >     + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

Comment: Are you using skype in the same machine during installation? If so, quit skype. Also make sure you are using 64 bit powershell interface.

Comment: Unfortunately for my sake, I was not running skype at the time and was using the 64 bit powershell interface.  Thanks for giving me something to look at, but still not working.

Comment: Which version of sitecore 9 you are trying to install? Have you updated the sif to its latest version? Which os you are using? Can you check the whether you can login user of database works?

Comment: I am installing version 9.3.0 and I got similar error like this. I had to delete what was created in IIS (identity server and application pool) - website was empty, bind only to port 80 and due to that not running.

Answer (score 31):

I got the similar error when installing the sitecore using SIF.I verified different configurations but finally found that IIS was not started. So i started IIS and error is gone.

Comment: Wow.. This has helped me! Wish the error message was better or may be smart enough to start IIS itself.

Comment: @HarshBaid You can write a wrapper script that has such smart functionality. In this case, it would be as simple as adding a `iisreset` command prior to calling the install scripts. I wrote about that and many other examples here: https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/docker-up-script

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue while installing the `Sitecore 10.3.1` instance on my local machine. To resolve this I have followed the below steps,

1. Open Services on your machine.
2. Search for the service `Windows Process Activation Service` and hit start if its stopped or restart the service.
   [image: Windows Process Activation Service]
3. Search for the service `World Wide Web Publishing Service` and hit start if its stopped or restart the service. [image: World Wide Web Publishing Service]
4. Close the existing Sitecore installation.
5. Restart the fresh Sitecore installation.

Thanks!