# Sitecore SIF installation identityserver issue

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework, identity-server

I am trying to install `Sitecore 10.1 XM`, via `SIF` but during installation I am getting error about `identityserver`, I see that identityserver is created on `IIS` side.
it is no other sites on IIS side, `MS SQL Server` can connect via the login that I provided for script.
what could be an issue of it ?

```
[------------------------------- IdentityServer_StopWebsite : ManageWebsite --------------------------------------------]
[IdentityServer_StopWebsite]:[Stop] mysite.identityserver
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Projects\ori\dev\deploy\configs\sitecore\10.1\XM1\XM1-SingleDeveloper.ps1:95 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:09
Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask : The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.3.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:644
char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageWebsiteTask
```

Comment: Did you check if IIS is running?  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/install-sitecoreconfiguration-the-property-value-cannot-be-found-on-this-obj

Comment: Can you check the property and value in XM1-SingleDeveloper.ps1 script line 95?

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay yes it is a call to Install-SitecoreConfiguration @@singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XM1-SingleDeveloper.log

Comment: @SumitBhatia seems like you are right !

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde Please mark this as complete if this resolved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check If this is the issue of `IIS`?

For this you need to check if IIS is started or not. If not, restart IIS and then check.